# how get images from gallery in my phone and show in page with flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gallery

I want to create a page like this with flutter

[image]

How to access the gallery in my phone and get the image to show?

Comment: Have you looked into Android [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [phoro_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager) library and show image and video from gallery like image that shown in question.
If you have a better solution, I would be happy to know it

Answer (score -1):

You can use **image_picker** library

> https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

```
  onTap: () async {
                     // TODO: to use image on camera button
                     final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
                     final XFile? photo =  await _picker.pickImage(
                                                  source: ImageSource.gallery);

                     if (photo == null) {
                            return;
                         }
                     ctrl.updateSelectedPicture(
                           photo.path);
                        },
```

Where *ctrl* is a reference to your controller class to call the function **updateSelectedPicture**

```
// Update profile photo
  void updateSelectedPicture(String path) {
    this.picture = path;

    this.pictureFile = File.fromUri(Uri(path: path));
  }
```

To show the image on view

```
getImage(String? picture) {
    return FileImage(File(picture!));
  }
```